# FreeTDS and PyODBC Random Connection Disconnects from server

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, sqlalchemy, pyodbc, freetds

For some reason, the following stack trace first shows up after roughly 16 hours or longer after starting the process and then shows up every hour or two after. I have other jobs on other servers that are daily, hourly, and every few minutes and they don't get this stack trace. The only difference I can see is this code has multiple jobs per scheduler whereas the others don't.

Stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 24, in _run_client
    h.run_hourly(start, end)
  File "/home/foo/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/foo/client/bar/helper.py", line 153, in run_hourly
    _run(_HOURLY_REQUEST, frequency, start, end, duration)
  File "/home/foo/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/foo/client/bar/helper.py", line 117, in _run
    bars = dr.get_bars(frequency)
  File "/home/foo/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/foo/client/bar/data_requests.py", line 35, in get_bars
    df = pd.read_sql(query, _ENGINE, params=params)
  File "/home/foo/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 415, in read_sql
chunksize=chunksize)
  File "/home/foo/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1084, in read_query
    result = self.execute(*args)
  File "/home/foo/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 975, in execute
    return self.connectable.execute(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/foo/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2055, in execute
    return connection.execute(statement, *multiparams, **params)
  File "/home/foo/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 945, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/home/foo/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 263, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/home/foo/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1053, in _execute_clauseelement
compiled_sql, distilled_params
  File "/home/foo/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1189, in _execute_context
context)
  File "/home/foo/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1386, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    self._autorollback()
  File "/home/foo/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 824, in _autorollback
    self._root._rollback_impl()
  File "/home/foo/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 703, in _rollback_impl
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(e, None, None, None, None)
  File "/home/foo/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1315, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    exc_info
  File "/home/foo/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 202, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "/home/foo/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 701, in _rollback_impl
    self.engine.dialect.do_rollback(self.connection)
  File "/home/foo/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 439, in do_rollback
    dbapi_connection.rollback()
DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('08S01', '[08S01] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Write to the server failed (20006) (SQLEndTran)')
```

The servers match in regards to the versions mentioned below.

Versions:
OS: Ubuntu 16.04.1
FreeTDS Package Versions: freetds-common:0.91-6.1build1, tdsodbc:amd64:0.91-6.1build1
PyODBC: 3.0.10
SQL Alchemy: 1.1.4

TSQL Output:

```
Compile-time settings (established with the "configure" script)
                        Version: freetds v0.91
         freetds.conf directory: /etc/freetds
 MS db-lib source compatibility: no
    Sybase binary compatibility: yes
                  Thread safety: yes
                  iconv library: yes
                    TDS version: 4.2
                          iODBC: no
                       unixodbc: yes
          SSPI "trusted" logins: no
                       Kerberos: yes
```

Test code:

app.py

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from dateutil import relativedelta
import traceback

from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
from bar import helper as h


def _run_client(resolution):
    try:
        if resolution == "hourly":
            # Had to create a temporary variable to make native datetimes
            t = datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(hours=1)
            end = datetime(t.year, t.month, t.day, t.hour)
            start = end - timedelta(hours=1)
            h.run_hourly(start, end)
        elif resolution == "daily":
            # Had to create a temporary variable to make native datetimes
            t = datetime.utcnow().date() - timedelta(days=1)
            end = datetime(t.year, t.month, t.day)
            start = end - timedelta(days=1)
            h.run_daily(start, end)
        else:
            # Had to create a temporary variable to make native datetimes
            t = datetime.utcnow().date().replace(
                day=1) - relativedelta.relativedelta(months=1)
            end = datetime(t.year, t.month, t.day)
            start = end - relativedelta.relativedelta(months=1)
            h.run_monthly(start, end)
    except:
        print "Current run failed:\n%s" % traceback.format_exc()


def _get_hourly_job(sched):
    args = ["hourly"]
    job = sched.add_job(_run_client, args=args, trigger="cron", hour="*", minute="0")
    return job


def _get_daily_job(sched):
    args = ["daily"]
    job = sched.add_job(_run_client, args=args, trigger="cron", hour="4", minute="0")
    return job


def _get_monthly_job(sched):
    args = ["monthly"]
    job = sched.add_job(_run_client, args=args, trigger="cron", day="1", hour="0", minute="0")
    return job

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sched = BlockingScheduler()
    hourly_job = _get_hourly_job(sched)
    daily_job = _get_daily_job(sched)
    monthly_job = _get_monthly_job(sched)

    try:
        sched.start()
    except:
        # Remove the jobs from memory since they finished
        hourly_job.remove()
        daily_job.remove()
        monthly_job.remove()

        sched.shutdown()
```

helper.py

```
from datetime import timedelta

import data_requests as dr

_HOURLY_REQUEST = Foo()
_HOURLY_REQUEST.resolution = "hourly"

_DAILY_REQUEST = Foo()
_DAILY_REQUEST.resolution = "daily"

_MONTHLY_REQUEST = Foo()
_MONTHLY_REQUEST.resolution = "monthly"


def _run(request, frequency, start, end, duration):
    bars = dr.get_bars(frequency)

    if bars.empty: 
        return None
    print "Bars = %i" % len(bars)


def run_daily(start, end):
    frequency = 86400
    duration = timedelta(hours=4)
    _run(_DAILY_REQUEST, frequency, start, end, duration)


def run_hourly(start, end):
    frequency = 3600
    duration = timedelta(minutes=30)
    _run(_HOURLY_REQUEST, frequency, start, end, duration)


def run_monthly(start, end):
    frequency = 1209600
    duration = timedelta(days=1)
    _run(_MONTHLY_REQUEST, frequency, start, end, duration)
```

data_requests.py

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, exc
from sqlalchemy.sql import text

_DB = "mssql+pyodbc://foo@stg-foo:FooBar@stg-foo.database.secure.windows.net:1433/foo?driver=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so&tds_version=7.2"
_ENGINE = create_engine(_DB)


def get_bars(frequency):
    query = text("""SELECT h.foo_id, s.id AS bar_id, u.timezone
                FROM foo h
                INNER JOIN bar s ON h.foo_id = s.foo_id
                AND s.frequency <= :frequency
                INNER JOIN test u ON u.id = h.test_id""")
    params = {
        "frequency": int(frequency)
    }

    try:
        df = pd.read_sql(query, _ENGINE, params=params)
    except exc.DBAPIError, e:
        # If connection is invalid (e.g. database restarted) execute the query
        # again
        if e.connection_invalidated:
            df = pd.read_sql(query, _ENGINE, params=params)
        else:
            raise e

    return df
```

I tried pymssql, but that segfaults with the latest version (2.1.3, freetds version 1.00.9), whereas pyodbc doesn't. I think this is a driver issue, but am having issues trying to work around it.

In addition, I followed SQL Alchemy's documentation on how to handle connection disconnects, but looking at the stack trace, it doesn't seem to be hitting the logic. Instead, it hits the else block and raises the error.

Comment: That error appears to be coming from farther up that stack than your Python layer. Given the timing, is there any kind of scheduled tasks on the SQL Server side which could be running at the specific times creating locking issues? The SQL Query in the error doesn't seem to be something that should take a while. When you run `tsql -C` what version of the TDS protocol is being reported?

Comment: @FlipperPA Not that I am aware of. After running tsql -C, it looks like it could be a conflict between the anaconda freetds that was installed with pymssql and the package manager freetds that was installed. I'll run it again for another hour and see if that was the issue.

Comment: @FlipperPA I've updated with some more details. It seems that it wasn't a conflict issue. I checked the sys.event_log table in the master database and it doesn't show any information other than successful connections. To me it looks like a connection issue, but for some reason the code I used in the SQL Alchemy documentation is not handling this scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the cause of the error. It seemed to be a coding issue after all. It took a long time to figure out, but it had to do with how I was making the calls with pandas. Apparently, pandas doesn't seem to close the connection when passing an engine instance. Here's the code that I used to fix the issue.

```
def _get_df(query, params=None):
    try:
        with _ENGINE.begin() as conn:
            df = pd.read_sql(query, conn, params=params)
    except exc.DBAPIError, e:
        # If connection is invalid (e.g. database restarted) execute the query
        # again
        if e.connection_invalidated:
            with _ENGINE.begin() as conn:
                df = pd.read_sql(query, conn, params=params)
        else:
            raise e
    return df
```