# pyodbc.OperationalError - Read from the server failed

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I am using `mssql` server in ubuntu, and tries to access using `pyodbc`

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connects="Driver=;SERVER=;DATABASE=;UID=;PWD=;port=;TDS_Version=8.0")
```

using this statement, I got access to the database,
I tried to read the data from the table using sqlalchemy from flask

```
session.query(table1).filter(table1.col>4).all()
```

I got this error

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pyodbc.OperationalError) ('08S01', '[08S01] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Write to the server failed (20006) (SQLExecDirectW)')

The important note: this error happens randomly, which means, when executing this query, sometimes, I got the data and sometimes, I got this error

A few times, I got this error:

> ERROR - sqlalchemy.pool.impl.QueuePool - Exception during reset or similar
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 502, in do_rollback
> dbapi_connection.rollback()
> pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08S01', '[08S01] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Write to the server failed (20006) (SQLEndTran)')

What is the possible reason for this error? Thanks.

Comment: You could try connecting with https://datacadamia.com/odbc/unix/isql to verify the driver is set correctly in ODBC, a simple `SELECT @@version` would confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below! and let me know if it works!!
from your statement - when you say sometimes it works and sometimes it dosen't - does the same query work again when you re-run to reset the conection again by running the create_engine again. if yes then please try setting up connection like below and try

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.engine import URL

connection_string = "DRIVER=;SERVER=;DATABASE=;UID=;PWD=;?autocommit=true"
connection_url = URL.create("mssql+pyodbc", query={"odbc_connect": connection_string})
engine = create_engine(connection_url)
```

I have added IMPORT URL from sqlalchemy, you can ignore it if you like (i prefer my connection this way)

now the main difference in my connection is , if you look at this line specifically

```
connection_string = "DRIVER=;SERVER=;DATABASE=;UID=;PWD=;?autocommit=true"
```

is using this in the end - *autocommit=true* - please give it a try.

Comment: the autocommit parameter is not working for this issue, do you know what is the possible reasons for this error, thanks

Comment: i found similar error here in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41143621/freetds-and-pyodbc-random-connection-disconnects-from-server  please, check the solution provided gives a way to use try catch method

Comment: @VishakRaj did the URL shared above, helped, please let us know !

Comment: Usually I used the try except block, still the link is not the optimal solution

Comment: check this link, the discussion is going on - https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/discussions/9137#discussioncomment-4757122

I metioned the even more details about this issue